# Can't change default command prompt conemu in visual studio

Tags: conemu

[link 1](https://superuser.com/questions/509642/how-to-change-the-default-terminal-emulator-on-windows-cmd)

it worked on win32 build configuration debug mode, but doesn't work on x64 build configuration debug mode.

how can i change default command prompt on x64 build config ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the x64 version from ConEmu, and set the same setting there.